# XCode IDE Library settings versus gcc make files

Tags: xcode, postgresql, makefile, osx-mavericks, osx-server

I have spent a lot of time researching how to compile a simple PostgreSQL test application written in C and I've got it to compile, run and connect to the PostgreSQL database that comes with Mavericks Server om my Mac Mini running OS X 10.9.3.

Then I decided to try using the Xcode IDE to compile and debug the same PostgreSQL code however, in Xcode I am getting references to Postgres methods listing 7 issues related to "Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error", including _PQclear, _PQconnectdb, PQerrorMessage, _PQexec, _PQfinish, _PQprint, _PQstatus. The final error is related to Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). Note: I'm not sure where to add the -ld parameters in the Xcode IDE or where to put the -v to find out more.

I have read many of the Stack Overflow items but most of them relate to iOS rather than OSX however I tried to figure out how to use many of those suggestions. Unfortunately I still am not able to figure out where to add the ld (LD) item for postgres similar to what I have in my make file. I tried adding and changing different settings on the Build Phases in the Xcode IDE but I keep getting these 8 issues.

In my code that I'm trying to compile from Xcode I changed one line to point to the location where the libpq-fe.h is as follows but I'm not sure if this is the correct or best approach:

```
#include </Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/include/libpq-fe.h>
```

**Here is my makefile that compiles using make pg_test**

```
## File: makefile
## Rules to create libpq sample application
LDLIBS  += -L/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/postgresql9.1/ -lpq
CFLAGS += -c -v -g -I/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/include/
LDFLAGS  += -g
pg_test: pg_test.o
```

**Here is my pg_test.c code**

```
// File: pg_test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
void process_query (PGconn * connection, const char * query_text ) {
  PGresult * result;
  PQprintOpt options = {0};

  if(( result = PQexec ( connection, query_text )) == NULL ) {
    printf( "%s\n", PQerrorMessage ( connection ));
    return;
  }

  options.header = 1;
  options.align = 1;
  options.fieldSep = "|";
  PQprint (stdout, result, &options );
  PQclear ( result );
}

int main ( ) {
  PGconn * connection;
  char * dbarg = "user=jerry password=test dbname=jletter hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432";
  connection = PQconnectdb(dbarg);

  if(  PQstatus( connection ) != CONNECTION_OK )
    printf( "%s\n", PQerrorMessage( connection ));
   else {
     process_query( connection, "SELECT * FROM friends" );
   }

  PQfinish ( connection );
  exit (0);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your XCode project is failing to link to `libpq`.

Comment: Yes, I knew that, I did understand what the errors meant. What my question is requesting is; where do I set these "XCode IDE Library settings" so that it points to my libpq file so that it is able to link? Your profile seem to indicate that your an expert on Postgres. Do you think you can figure out where to set those settings in the Xcode IDE?

Comment: Not without a Mac I'm afraid. That's why I just left a comment, not an answer. Now, if you can convince Apple to let us developer types run their precious operating system in a VM like everyone else does, sure... :S

Comment: There is a guy in Montreal Canada that another stack-overflow member mentioned to me, named Danil Aroustamov. This guy runs a service called XCodeClub.com that  offers up VM's of Mac Mini's running Mavericks Server. The first few sentences of his website says the following: "Connect remotely to your own Dedicated Mac Virtual Machine - Virtual Mac running latest licensed
Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.3 with latest XCode 5.1.1 with your own private iOS Simulators! Completely configured and ready to use!   - - -   If he is doing it, I bet you could do it too.

Comment: Great service - I'll check it out, i may need something like that soon. It works because the underlying hardware is Apple though. You can run an OSX VM guest on top of an OSX host on Apple hardware but because of licensing and the TPM you can't do it on top of a on-Apple host.

Comment: BTW I think you want https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/UsingDynamicLibraries.html and http://www.maximporges.com/2010/02/08/adding-headers-and-external-libraries-to-xcode-projects/